# Npm Package Install Problem (found 23 vulnerabilities)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I tried to install the package. But I saw this error.How to solve this problem ?

[image: problem screentshot]

Comment: Did you read the message?

Comment: Please do not present text renderings: copy&paste it into your question (as a block quote where appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

It means that there are 23 packages in your package.json (or dependencies of packages in your package.json) that have reported vulnerabilities. If you own the code base you could try to update the dependencies to newer versions and hope that the authors have released new versions with the vulnerabilities fixed. If you don't own the code then you should contact the person who does.

Comment: Then the vulnerabilities are in that package. You should contact the author and then use another package instead.

Comment: Then its probably a globally installed package thats causing issues. Your screenshot seems to indicate `react-responsive`

Answer (score 0):

It means that there are packages in `package-lock.json` that have publicly-disclosed vulnerabilities in them.

How to correctly handle this will depend a lot of things. Easiest is probably to run `npm audit fix` which will fix all the ones that it can without introducing incompatible changes (as determined by semantic versioning, so it's far from a guarantee). That will update your `package-lock.json` in the process.

If there are vulnerabilities that cannot be fixed without introducing an potentially-incompatible change (again, as determined by semantic versioning), then you will have to do more than `npm audit fix`. Fortunately, `npm audit fix` usually gives you instructions. One thing it can't do for you, though, is test and fix any issues that result from the incompatible upgrades.